# jquery - undesired jump effect (it occurs often and I don't understand why)

Tags: jquery, hide, show

On the code above, we:

1) Click on Categoria A and then, 
2) click on one of the bold titles that appear.

You will notice that, while expanding instead of the movement to be smooth, it jumps near the end of the show process. (It seems that when it finds a `<p>` he jumps);

What could be the cause of such a behavior?

Here his the related code: code:

```
$('#btCategoriaA').click(function() {
            $('#btCategoriaA').toggleClass('selecionado');
            $('#listaCategoriaA').slideToggle('slow', function() {
           });
        });


        $('#btCategoriaB').click(function() {
            $('#btCategoriaB').toggleClass('selecionado');
            $('#listaCategoriaB').slideToggle('slow', function() {
            });
        });

        $('#btCategoriaC').click(function() {
            $('#btCategoriaC').toggleClass('selecionado');
            $('#listaCategoriaC').slideToggle('slow', function() {
           });
        });



        function mostraDesafio(num){
            $('#detalheDesafio'+num).slideToggle('slow');
        }
```

Should I provide more information,please, just let me know about it.

K. Regards,
MEM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your `.detalheDesafio` element a definite width in CSS. That should fix it.

```
.detalheDesafio {
    width: 308px;
}
```

I don't remember why it is needed, but the `.slideToggle()` method requires it somehow.

Comment: I was struggling with this for so many sites. Thanks a lot! ;)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to remove the top-margins of the upper < p > element within the element I was trying to .slideToggle(). That removed the jumping bug at the end.

Other good suggestions about this bug on: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/